# Variables will not hold a value in a foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a very odd problem with the following code. For some reason I can't get $id1 or $id2 to hold values unless it is placed outside the if and else...if statements. The variables simply will not register. Does anybody see what I am doing wrong? I'm at a loss..

```
public function addCommentToStartpageWall() {
        $userid = $this->session->userdata("userid");
        $postingUserId = $this->input->post("postinguserid");

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM churchmembers");
        $row = $query->row();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            if ($postingUserId == $row->cMuserId) { // check to see what church the posting user is a member of
                $id1 = $row->cMchurchId; // if posting user is a member of a church set it to var id1
            } if ($userid == $row->cMuserId) { // check to see what church myuserid is a member of
                $id2 = $row->cMchurchId; // if myuserid is a member of a church set it to var2
            } if ($id1 == $id2) { // if posting user and myuserid are a member of the same church process the following
                echo json_encode(array('id1' => $id1, 'isMembershipSame' => true));
            } elseif ($id1 != $id2) { // if posting user and myuserid are not a member of the same user process the following
                echo json_encode(array('id1' => $id1, 'isMembershipSame' => false));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not initialising them except inside the `if` statements - might that be causing issues?

Comment: I've placed `$id1 = ""; $id2 = ""` outside the foreach loop. but nothing happened.

Comment: Is `$postingUserId == $row->cMuserId` or is `$userid == $row->cMuserId`?

Comment: Could you try adding `var_dump($id)` between every line of code, in that case? So you can see when it's set, and when it disappears?

Comment: And are you sure that `$row` is returned as an object, and not as an array?

Comment: $row is returning multiple values... so im assuming its an array

Comment: Why do you have `$row = $query->row();` before `foreach ($query->result() as $row) {`?

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby - I suggest you check that it's in the format that you're assuming, in that case.

Comment: Echo `$row->cMuserId`, make sure it's equal to `$userid` or `$postingUserId`.

Comment: Some of the results that are displaying are very odd. I need to go through and completely rethink my logic. one problem i've just noticed is im outputting an array to jquery, so it'll never recognize it. and i believe this code is not going to work well.

Comment: While loop would continuously set a new value on every loops start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like i was wrong too, above answer is correct.

I would recommend resetting your $id1 and $id2 variables each loop however, to prevent them from holding values from the previous iteration:

```
foreach ... 
{
    $id1 = "";
    $id2 = "";

    // ...
}
```

Comment: PHP has function scope not block scope.  If you declare a variable inside an `if`, it's declared in the highest function's (or global) scope.

Comment: Forgot how bad PHP was; the answer is that your $id1 and $id2 variables are never being set because your initial if statements do not hold.

Comment: Ohh... so the first two if statements are not equaling each other?

Comment: Yep, perhaps `$row = $query->row();` is redundant and causing problems. I'd also `print_r($row)` inside the loop to see what values have been retrieved from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare/initiate those variables outside of the loop. I believe it's matter of scope - once the loop ends, those variables are trashed.

Edit: I was wrong - I'd guess it's that your if/else aren't evaluating properly.

Comment: PHP has function scope, not block scope.